# is Windows Subsystem for Linux a complete replacement for Linux virtual machines?

Tags: virtual-machine, windows-subsystem-for-linux, bitbake

I'm investigating transitioning from Ubuntu 18 virtual machine to Ubuntu 18 WSL.

I know WSL has no gui, which is fine, but . . .

**QUESTIONS**

1. Besides lower memory usage, what is the advantage of using WSL instead of VM?.
2. Do I lose any capability by moving to WSL?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1051525/windows-subsystem-for-linux-wsl-what-cant-i-do-with-the-ubuntu-application-f

Comment: @HansPassant thanks.